# Remove string from a vector in R

Tags: r, string

I have a vector that looks like

```
> inecodes
   [1] "01001" "01002" "01049" "01003" "01006" "01037" "01008" "01004" "01009" "01010" "01011"
  [12] "01013" "01014" "01016" "01017" "01021" "01022" "01023" "01046" "01056" "01901" "01027"
  [23] "01019" "01020" "01028" "01030" "01031" "01032" "01902" "01033" "01036" "01058" "01034"
  [34] "01039" "01041" "01042" "01043" "01044" "01047" "01051" "01052" "01053" "01054" "01055"
```

And I want to remove these "numbers" from this vector:

```
>pob
 [1] "01001-Alegría-Dulantzi"           "01002-Amurrio"                   
 [3] "01049-Añana"                      "01003-Aramaio"                   
 [5] "01006-Armiñón"                    "01037-Arraia-Maeztu"             
 [7] "01008-Arratzua-Ubarrundia"        "01004-Artziniega"                
 [9] "01009-Asparrena"                  "01010-Ayala/Aiara"               
[11] "01011-Baños de Ebro/Mañueta"      "01013-Barrundia"                 
[13] "01014-Berantevilla"               "01016-Bernedo"                   
[15] "01017-Campezo/Kanpezu"            "01021-Elburgo/Burgelu"           
[17] "01022-Elciego"                    "01023-Elvillar/Bilar"            
[19] "01046-Erriberagoitia/Ribera Alta"
```

They are longer that these samples and they don't have the same length. The answer must to be like following:

```
>pob
     [1] "Alegría-Dulantzi"           "Amurrio"                   
     [3] "Añana"                      "Aramaio"                   
     [5] "Armiñón"                    "Arraia-Maeztu"             
     [7] "Arratzua-Ubarrundia"        "Artziniega"                
     [9] "Asparrena"                  "Ayala/Aiara"               
    [11] "Baños de Ebro/Mañueta"      "Barrundia"                 
    [13] "Berantevilla"               "Bernedo"                   
    [15] "Campezo/Kanpezu"            "Elburgo/Burgelu"           
    [17] "Elciego"                    "Elvillar/Bilar"            
    [19] "Erriberagoitia/Ribera Alta"
```

Comment: Yes, but if you don't understand the question you must not rate it negative, so past to the next and don't try to answer only the easy questions.

Comment: FYI, someone probably downvoted your question because the vectors you provided are not easy to reproduce (just try to copy and paste what you have posted in your console and run, it doesn't give you the vector you would want). Instead, post the _code_ that you used to create those vectors.

Comment: The question was clear but the "premium" users will not never understan because you only want to ask the easy question.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 8):

Not sure why you needed `inecodes` at all, since you can use `sub` to remove all digits:

```
sub('^\\d+-', '', pob)
```

**Result:**

```
 [1] "Alegría-Dulantzi"           "Amurrio"                    "Añana"                     
 [4] "Aramaio"                    "Armiñón"                    "Arraia-Maeztu"             
 [7] "Arratzua-Ubarrundia"        "Artziniega"                 "Asparrena"                 
[10] "Ayala/Aiara"                "Baños de Ebro/Mañueta"      "Barrundia"                 
[13] "Berantevilla"               "Bernedo"                    "Campezo/Kanpezu"           
[16] "Elburgo/Burgelu"            "Elciego"                    "Elvillar/Bilar"            
[19] "Erriberagoitia/Ribera Alta"
```

One reason that you might need `inecodes` is that you have codes in `pob` that don't exist in `inecodes`, but that doesn't seem like the case here. If you insist on using `inecodes` to remove numbers from `pob`, you can use `str_replace_all` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace_all(pob, setNames(rep("", length(inecodes)), paste0(inecodes, "-")))
```

This gives you the exact same result:

```
 [1] "Alegría-Dulantzi"           "Amurrio"                    "Añana"                     
 [4] "Aramaio"                    "Armiñón"                    "Arraia-Maeztu"             
 [7] "Arratzua-Ubarrundia"        "Artziniega"                 "Asparrena"                 
[10] "Ayala/Aiara"                "Baños de Ebro/Mañueta"      "Barrundia"                 
[13] "Berantevilla"               "Bernedo"                    "Campezo/Kanpezu"           
[16] "Elburgo/Burgelu"            "Elciego"                    "Elvillar/Bilar"            
[19] "Erriberagoitia/Ribera Alta"
```

**Data:**

```
inecodes = c("01001", "01002", "01049", "01003", "01006", "01037", "01008", 
"01004", "01009", "01010", "01011", "01013", "01014", "01016", 
"01017", "01021", "01022", "01023", "01046", "01056", "01901", 
"01027", "01019", "01020", "01028", "01030", "01031", "01032", 
"01902", "01033", "01036", "01058", "01034", "01039", "01041", 
"01042", "01043", "01044", "01047", "01051", "01052", "01053", 
"01054", "01055")

pob = c("01001-Alegría-Dulantzi", "01002-Amurrio", "01049-Añana", "01003-Aramaio", 
"01006-Armiñón", "01037-Arraia-Maeztu", "01008-Arratzua-Ubarrundia", 
"01004-Artziniega", "01009-Asparrena", "01010-Ayala/Aiara", "01011-Baños de Ebro/Mañueta", 
"01013-Barrundia", "01014-Berantevilla", "01016-Bernedo", "01017-Campezo/Kanpezu", 
"01021-Elburgo/Burgelu", "01022-Elciego", "01023-Elvillar/Bilar", 
"01046-Erriberagoitia/Ribera Alta")
```

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer... Please kindly leave a comment so I can improve on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)

for(code in inecodes) {
  ix <- which(str_detect(pob, code))
  pob[ix] <- unlist(str_split(pob, "-", 2))[2]
}
```

Comment: This code has a lot of computational code, I'm sorry

Comment: Do you need a more optimized solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Match should be much faster

```
pos<-which(!is.na(pob[match(sub('^([0-9]+)-.*$','\\1',pob),inecodes)]))
pob[pos]<-sub('^[0-9]+-(.*)$','\\1',pob[pos])
```

Please do post the timings if you manage to get this. Match usually solves many computational issues for large data sets lookup. Would like to see if there are any opposite scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter than `sub`, `str_detect` and `str_replace` is `str_remove`:

```
library(stringr)

c("01001-Alegría-Dulantzi", "01002-Amurrio") %>%
  str_remove("[0-9]*-")
```

returns

```
"Alegría-Dulantzi" "Amurrio"
```