# How to remove numbers if a string starts with numbers, but keep everything else (in r)?

Tags: r, string, vector, split, character

I am working with data in R and have a string related question.
If I have a vector (say books),

```
books <- c('123 Book1 331','51 Book2','Book3 69','Book4')
```

I want to split strings that start with numbers and keep the rest, else leave it as it is. 
I would like to extract info in a way as shown below:

```
[1] "Book1 331" "Book2"     "Book3 69"  "Book4"
```

What package do i have to use in R? And what function?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142156/remove-string-from-a-vector-in-r) is similar to your case.

Comment: @jazzuro thank you for pointing it out. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get the answer with the solution provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another variant using `sub` which does not require a capture group:

```
books <- c('123 Book1 331','51 Book2','Book3 69','Book4')
sub("^\\d+\\s+", "", books)

[1] "Book1 331" "Book2"     "Book3 69"  "Book4"
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `gsub` with your own regular expression. E.g.:

```
books <- c('123 Book1 331','51 Book2','Book3 69','Book4')

gsub("^.*?([a-zA-Z]+.+)", "\\1", books)

[1] "Book1 331" "Book2"     "Book3 69"  "Book4"
```

Comment: Nice :)! `gsub("^[[:digit:] ]+", "\\1", books) works too, right?
`

Comment: Yeah true, the other way around basically. Although you'll have to remove trailing whitespace still !